# Convert dynamic object into desired type

Tags: c#

It is not quite normal situation so I will do it step by step.

- I am having object of type `Tuple<DataTable, ConcurrentDictionary<int, Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>>>`
- I populate it.
- I serialize it using `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(thatOjbect)`
- I turn it into `bytes array`
- I save it somewhere.

Now problem appear when I read

- I get `byte array` and convert them into `object` (I need to do it like this since it is part of some complex class and at point of loading bytes I still do not know what type of object is stored)
- I pass that `object` (which is dynamic and has `Item1` which represents `DataTable` and `Item2` which represents `ConcurrentDictionary<int, Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>>` visible in debugger with all info)
- I try use it multiple ways (explained down) and fail every time.

First way I tried was simple `Tuple<DataTable, ConcurrentDictionary<int, Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>>> myObj = receivedObject as Tuple<DataTable, ConcurrentDictionary<int, Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>>>;` and this one returns `null` and I see dynamic object is populated

Second thing I try is again serialize dynamic object and then deserialize it into `Tuple<DataTable, ConcurrentDictionary<int, Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>>>` but it says it failed in deserialization (this one worked when I had type `Tuple<DataTable>` since first way on this one has not worked)

So how can I convert dynamic object which I got from deserialization into desired type?

Here is how it looks in debugger:
[image]

Comment: Hmm, the dynamic object already has a description, right ?

Comment: What do you mean by description?

Comment: The byte array is coverted to an object, right ?

Comment: That is right, to the object

Comment: Why don't you use JSON instead of byte array :-?

Comment: There are problems when deserialize, which make your properties null

Comment: Have you tried simplifying things (as an experiment). If I remember correctly, DataSets and DataTables don't serialize/deserialize very well. Try (as an experiment) to just push your DataTable through this process. If it were me, I'd convert the DataTable to a collection of typed objects before serialization

Comment: I'd say that the dynamic you have is a sort of dictionary with some DLR facade. And you can't just cast a dictionary to a type, even if it has the exact same properties as the target type. What you can do instead is instantiate the requested type with properties from said dictionary. If you feel like that's really a lot of work that a seralizer could do, you are not wrong.

Comment: @ZdeněkJelínek figured it out few mins ago and just started writing. I found out what it is and solution but do not know why it happens. Will write it now.

Comment: Honestly, you lost me at the part where you said "I am having object of type Tuple of DataTable and ConcurrentDictionary of int and Tuple of DateTime and DateTime".  There's no charge for encapsulating all that crazy in a class and giving it some usable logical names

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is problem with serialization where I got string with additional objects around (`few more [] around whole object and inside individual items`). I do not know why it does happen but what I do is I cast it to `IEnumerable<object>` and get `First()` to get rid of first `"facade"`. Then I am left with real object with two items which are also `"facaded"` so now to convert to my `DataTable` I need to also get rid of "facade" with `First()` and then I can deserialize that object.

Final code looks like this:

```
IEnumerable<object> obj = _poruka.Tag.AdditionalInfo as IEnumerable<object>;
DataTable dtt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(
    JsonConvert.SerializeObject((obj.First() as IEnumerable<object>).First()));
ConcurrentDictionary<int, Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>> cd =
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ConcurrentDictionary<int, Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>>>(
    JsonConvert.SerializeObject((obj.Last() as IEnumerable<object>).First()));
```